# Why URL not found Error in redirect URI?

Tags: jquery, office365, azure-active-directory, redirect, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on office 365 API where I am allowing user to login through its Microsoft account. For this I have mention a redirect URL in the Request and after successful login the API should redirect me to the same URL.
The problem is when it is being redirected to the URL, it shows me U

> RL not found Error

But when I copy same URL and hit on the another tab its working fine. When I am testing it locally its working fine.

[image]

Here is the Same Url:

```
https://trimaxamericas.opsarcportal.com/EmailToClient/Auth
```

Comment: which method you are using for accessing the url ?

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" + Office365ClientID + "&redirect_uri=" + Office365RedirectURI + "&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dLr2WDVp9oEU8SZGpc8IgkpBlVlK6Oi_Fe9luCdnOF39RtrMLYXAwLlFB37utpCfiNKk0hA-ZYg8sjKO4dh3rNS6PEBAGpZkKYmsLhs-4iVDmHI89c6XihppJ4NgoTrbtZmrStzazFQLjQ-xaZy6PlJ7QofQi3UXbrpJYJRf5RSdIqDLm5ZV-DAnpVQiaBWQ-cU5pvC2J4nH7dTk9CEnFzes5px0Y9rBWK2T5FeKb31wXjYGiYL53lX-qd4I-JGT6&nonce=636597353256924107`